How access specific child object variable from C# ADS
I am developping a project using Twincat3 and C# ADS for the HMI.
For structure purpose, i want to use Twincat POO. I am new to Twincat and dont understand how to connect nested child objects to my HMI using ADS handler.
I have 1 parent function block
//Example
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Parent
VAR
    iParentVariable: INT;
END_VAR

and multiple child function block that extends FB_Parent
//Example
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Child
VAR
    iChildVariable: INT;
END_VAR

In my program, i have an array of FB_Parent. On initialization command from my custom HMI (C#), i create new FB_Child dynamically:
// Example
fbChild := __NEW(FB_Child);
array[0] := fbChild^;
__DELETE(fbChild);

The problem is that I can't create handler and access child variable from my HMI (C#):
client = new AdsClient
{
    Timeout = 500
};
client.Connect(parameters.AmsNetID, parameters.AdsPort);
handler = client.CreateVariableHandle("PRG_MAIN.arrConveyors[0].iChildVariable");

How can i still use POO and dynamic object creation in Twincat and access child variable in C# trough ADS ?
Thanks for you help !
I tried to change the definition of my array:

Using POINTER OF FB_Parent
Using Interface instead of Parent class

Nothing worked.

2 questions :
Do you see your child variables in Twincat XAE Shell, in Online mode.
What is the error / exception that happened when you call CreateVariableHandle ?

I think that somewhere along the way Beckhoff "broke" arrays for work with ADS libraries. I get a bunch of "Method not implemented" when getting to arrays, which used to work, but does not any more (I am using SymbolLoaderFactory in C#). What is your TwinCAT and C# Nuget version?

I edited my answer, using variable handle. You should see the basic of how to use it now hopefully.

As I already wrote in the comment, I think that Beckhoff had changed something in how ADS is used with their libraries for TwinCAT. As an example, here is a small app I made for testing, which worked for arrays not over a year ago. When I try to run it now, it says "Method not implemented" when i want to fetch ISymbol which has typearray. This is also something I noticed not long ago in a custom app we use for our machines, where I would always declared the PLC's NetId as an array, but it stopped working not over a year ago, but unfortunately I did not have time to look at it and it was not crucial... If anyone has more clue, please feel free to send a solution or what the problem might be, my guess is TwinCAT runtime changed (we do not update ADS nuget, for this exact reason)?
NuGet version: Beckhoff.TwinCAT.Ads 6.1.203
TwinCAT version: 4024.32
Here is the error thrown from the library, I omitted the Array check in this example:

Array members used to be treated as sub symbols, but now the code crashes there, as seen in this image:

Just as additional reference, this is how I would read symbols from the target , code is shortened just showing method and property required:
    public IEnumerable<ISymbol>? SymbolCollection
    {
        get;
        private set;
    } = [];

    public void Connect()
    {
        this.adsClient ??= new();
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.NetId))
            {
                this.adsClient.Connect(AmsNetId.Local, this.Port);
            }
            else
            {
                this.adsClient.Connect(this.NetId, Convert.ToInt32(this.Port));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        this.adsClient.ConnectionStateChanged += this.OnConnectionStateChanged;
        this.adsClient.AdsStateChanged += this.OnAdsStateChanged;

        this.SymbolCollection = this.GetSymbols();      
    }

    private List<ISymbol>? GetSymbols()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.adsClient != null && this.adsClient.IsConnected)
            {
                IDynamicSymbolLoader dynamicSymbolLoader = (IDynamicSymbolLoader)SymbolLoaderFactory
                    .Create(this.adsClient, SymbolLoaderSettings.DefaultDynamic);

                return [.. dynamicSymbolLoader.Symbols];
            }
            else
            {
                return default;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

As an additional point, here is what I get if I skip looking at arrays, the displayed window is just the UI of the app, which calls the upper code:


Edit
I went ahead and tried using the variable handle. After some testing I managed to deconstruct the data from the PLC.
Here is my PLC code:
{attribute 'enable_dynamic_creation'}
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Parent
VAR_INPUT
        iChildVar   : INT;
END_VAR

PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    arrParent   : ARRAY[0..10] OF FB_Parent;
    fbParent    : POINTER TO FB_Parent;
    bCreate     : BOOL;
END_VAR

IF bCreate THEN
    bCreate := FALSE;
    fbParent := __NEW(FB_Parent);
    // For testing when setting value of the array from the dynamically created object
    fbParent^.iChildVar := 16#ABC;
    arrParent[0] := fbParent^;
    __DELETE(fbPArent);
END_IF

// For testing of the 5th element, to confirm correct data layout
arrParent[5].iChildVar := 555;

Creating a C# console app:
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        var client = new TwinCAT.Ads.AdsClient();
        client.Connect(TwinCAT.Ads.AmsNetId.Local, 851);

        var parentArrayHandle = client.CreateVariableHandle("MAIN.arrParent");
        Parent[] parentArray = (Parent[])client.ReadAny(parentArrayHandle, typeof(Parent[]), [11]);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0, Size = 16)]
public class Parent 
{
    Int64 Reserved;
    Int16 iChildVar;
}

Running the app, you can confirm the result via the watch window:


Some explanation and perhaps a question for others.
On Beckhoff documentation, it says that for structs/classes, you need to use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0, Size = 16)], it says for TC3 set pack to 0, for TC2 set to 1, example differs... I additionaly set the size to 16 bytes, looking at memory area from TwinCAT's memory tool (PLC -> Windows -> Show memory view) - first 8 bytes were always reserved as it seems, after that there were last 8 bytes, first 2 of which was our iChildVar, the rest were empty until next array member, as can be seen here:

This can change depending on the size of your objects, assuming TC is using 16 byte alignment, if you go over the 16th byte you will have 32 bytes etc...

Have you tested the latest TwinCAT.Ads (6.1.244 as we speak). I don't know about your issue, but in the past there have been many bug fixes that have at least helped me. And as normally with Beckhoff, the release notes are missing or at least suck...

@Quirzo Tried with latest version, same result happens :/

If you think there is a bug, you could try to contact Beckhoff developers through nuget ("Contact owners"). I did that once and the response was very friendly

@Quirzo I contacted our local Beckhoff support regarding this, we have a good connection with them.

Actually, the problem in my case was that I was casting to List<ISymbol> from ISymbolCollection<IList> and that failed. Latest version is good, but latest .NET 4 version has a bug where it can't read ALIAS data types as far as I can see. Not sure how to proceed, is it fine if I delete me first observation from the answer since it is wrong?
